# VR Cursor Additional Sections Fading In Each Image One at a Time on Pointer Enter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a cursor of which I am using within a VR set up for Oculus.

The cursor when interacting with an interactive object is to react by fading in one of four Image Components by using color. This is to represent loading.

I have this set up by doing the following: 
An event trigger is set up on a button.
The event trigger has an On Pointer Enter section. 
The on pointer Section has the cursor loaded into it. 
The cursor is made up of a parent and four children.
The four children are an Image List within the script.

When the cursor hovers over the button they all fade in together.

This is nearly correct however I would like them to fade in once the previous has finished fading in.

[image: This may help]

```
float waitTime = 10.00f;
bool switchOn = false;
public List<Image> CursorLoaders = new List<Image>();


void Update()

{
    if (switchOn)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            StartCoroutine(FadeIn(CursorLoaders[i]));
        }
    }
}



public IEnumerator FadeIn(Image CursorPiece)
{
    float ElapsedTime = 0.0f;
    float TotalTime = 0.5f;

    while (ElapsedTime < TotalTime)
    {
        ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        CursorPiece.color = Color.Lerp(new Color(CursorPiece.color.r, CursorPiece.color.g, CursorPiece.color.b, 0.0f), new Color(CursorPiece.color.r, CursorPiece.color.g, CursorPiece.color.b, 1), (ElapsedTime / TotalTime));

        yield return null;
    }
}

public void ButtonCountDown()
{
    switchOn = true;

}
```

I have looked up on the asset store for similar things including the VR Samples - it majorly uses fillamount and orientation - which are good but not for this. I have also created WaitForSeconds inside the coRoutine and I have also Tried adding another coroutine with the wait for.  I'm scratching my head a bit.  I finally looked online for similar incremental fade examples or ways to change things one after the other but to no avail.

Comment: how about setting up a fade method for each section individually, and setting/checking a bool to see when the time has elapsed far enough to fade the previous image enough before moving to the next one

Comment: I was thinking the same thing - but I was wondering - would it be cleaner.  However perhaps your are thinking of this inside the co routine; like a way to stop the others until it's completed.  I'm seeing what I can be doing with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing something like the following, you can fade each image while not being constrained within a for-loop.

```
void Update()
{
    if (switchOn)
        FadeImages();
}

int counter = 0;
void FadeImages()
{
    ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
    Image CursorPiece = CursorLoaders[counter];
    CursorPiece.color = Color.Lerp(new Color(CursorPiece.color.r, CursorPiece.color.g, CursorPiece.color.b, 0.0f), new Color(CursorPiece.color.r, CursorPiece.color.g, CursorPiece.color.b, 1), (ElapsedTime / TotalTime));

    if (ElapsedTime > TotalTime) //if the image has completely faded, move to the next one
    {
        ElapsedTime = 0; // reset fade timer
        counter++; // increment CursorLoader[] index
    }
    if (counter >= 4) // if you have faded all the elements, stop the method.
        switchOn = false;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I think I've got into a habit of using CoRoutines for transitions and tend to forget about functions as a solution for this.  Though I am sure as I progress I'll be able to solve this using a coroutine.  There is a lesson in this for me.  Thank you again.  It is the loop that is jumping me to the next list object instantly - is that right?

Comment: I think coroutines may be the cleaner way to go about it, but I find something like this simpler and just as just effective, especially since I am not super comfortable with Coroutines either! With your for loop in the Update I am still scratching my head on how it worked at all. Something for me to learn as well.

Comment: That makes me feel better. I suppose it's a matter of learning trough experience. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Add a delay to your IEnumerator function. This was trivial to add and should work just fine. Then when you call `StartCoroutine` on this you tell the method which piece *and* how long to wait before starting to fade (probably some value multiplied by the array index).

```
public IEnumerator FadeIn(Image CursorPiece, float delayTime)
{
    float ElapsedTime = 0.0f;
    float TotalTime = 0.5f;

    while (ElapsedTime < delayTime)
    {
        ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    ElapsedTime = 0;
    while (ElapsedTime < TotalTime)
    {
        ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        CursorPiece.color = Color.Lerp(new Color(CursorPiece.color.r, CursorPiece.color.g, CursorPiece.color.b, 0.0f), new Color(CursorPiece.color.r, CursorPiece.color.g, CursorPiece.color.b, 1), (ElapsedTime / TotalTime));

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no doubt it was trival and with some more work from myself that it would work.  Thank you for your effort and your insight!